# Select query using a map

Tags: sql-server

```
CREATE TABLE grid_rows(
    [row_id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [column_id] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [column_val] [decimal](18, 6) NULL   
)
// (row_id, column_id) is a composite primary query
```

For a given `Map<column_id, column_value>` what would be the select query to get the `row_id`?

Table values:

```
1 k1 v1
1 k2 v2
1 k3 v3
2 k1 v1
2 k5 v5
2 k6 v6
```

How to get the `row_id` i.e 1 which matches all the key value pairs of `{k1:v1,k2:v2,k3,v3}`?

Comment: Can you explain what a `Map` is? Is this in some specific client-side language, ORM, framework, etc.? This concept does not seem familiar to me in SQL Server.

Comment: java along with ibatis framework

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use a `HAVING` clause with an aggregate function and a `CASE` expression to get the result, similar to this:

```
select row_id
from dbo.grid_rows
group by row_id
having 
  sum(case when column_id = 'k1' and column_val = 'v1' then 1 else 0 end) > 0
  and sum(case when column_id = 'k2' and column_val = 'v2' then 1 else 0 end) > 0
  and sum(case when column_id = 'k3' and column_val = 'v3' then 1 else 0 end) > 0;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/83d06/2)

The `CASE` expression checks that the `column_id` and the `column_val` match the key-value pair that you are checking for, if they match then the `sum()` gets a total value for the pair.  Each key-value pair must have a total of greater than zero in order for the `row_id` to be included.